# How to set class path for servlet-api.jar file in linux

Tags: java, linux

I want to compile the servlet in the Linux System.
For that I need to set the classpath for servlet-api.jar.
How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/solaris/classpath.html) describes how to set classpath in solaris or linux. Also try [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html).

Answer (score 0):

Same way as any other OS: use the `javac.exe -classpath` argument.

Or learn how to compile using Ant.

Or use an IDE that helps you.